# How to avoid java.net.UnknownHostException while parsing HTML content to generate Pdf file using iText

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I want to convert some HTML content into a PDF file. The problem I'm facing is that the HTML content has some `<img>` tags with absolute image urls. Hence the

```
HTMLWorker.parse()
```

method throws following exception in case there is no network connectivity.

```
ExceptionConverter: java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.com
```

Is there a way to avoid this exception in such case and generate a pdf without any image?

I'm using iText-5.0.5 library.

Comment: Always try the image paths using the relative URL from configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your **ImageProvider** and when there is a problem retrieving the image just return null, like

```
public static class MyImageProvider implements ImageProvider {
    public Image getImage(String src, Map<String, String> h, ChainedProperties cprops, DocListener doc) {
        try {
            return Image.getInstance(IMAGE_URL); //create IMAGE_URL from src parameter
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Then you should use the HTMLWorker with this provider

```
 HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 map.put(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new MyImageProvider());
 HTMLWorker.parseToList(new FileReader(HTML), null, map);
```